# How can I multiply all the values within a column range and row range?

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a df that looks like this:

| Name | No1 | No2 | No 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jack | 10 | 20 | 30 |
| Eli | 10 | 20 | 30 |
| Mae | 10 | 20 | 30 |
| Jack | 10 | 20 | 30 |

I want to multiply all values by a factor of 10 in columns 2:4 (so all columns excluding the Name column) and I only want to select rows where `Name == Jack`.

so, my final data table should look like this:

| Name | No1 | No2 | No 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jack | 100 | 200 | 300 |
| Eli | 10 | 20 | 30 |
| Mae | 10 | 20 | 30 |
| Jack | 100 | 200 | 300 |

I've tried various iterations of the following:

```
df %>% 
         filter(Name == "Jack") %>% 
         select(No1:No3) %>%
         df*10
```

including

```
df %>% 
         filter(Name == "Jack") %>% 
         df[2:4]*10
```

and I've also tried and if statement:

```
new_df <- if(df$name == "Jack"){
          df[2:4]*10}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may use `across` to loop over the columns that starts with 'No', then create a logical condition based on the 'Name' column, use either `ifelse/if_else` or `case_when` to do the change based on the logic

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(across(c(No1, No2, No3),
    ~ case_when(Name == "Jack" ~ .x * 10, TRUE ~ as.numeric(.x))))
```

It can be passed as an index as well

```
df %>%
    mutate(across(c(2, 3, 4), # or if it is a range 2:4
        ~ case_when(Name == "Jack" ~ .x * 10, TRUE ~ as.numeric(.x))))
```

---

Or in `base R`, subset the columns and the rows (based on the logic), and assign back after multiplying with 10

```
df[df$Name == "Jack", -1] <- df[df$Name == "Jack", -1] * 10
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Name = c("Jack", "Eli", "Mae", "Jack"), No1 = c(10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L), No2 = c(20L, 20L, 20L, 20L), No3 = c(30L, 30L, 
30L, 30L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: when I use the base R solution I get : `Error in FUN(left, right) : non-numeric argument to binary operator`. also I can't use your first solution where the mutation searches for columns that start with `NO` because in my actual dataset the columns do not have common characters, sorry about that.

Comment: @BrendaThompson you can specify the column index or column names as `across(c(No1, No2, No3),..`   In the second solution, I assumed that there are only 4 columns, and it is the first column you don't want to change i.e. why i used `-1`.  You can pass a vector of column names as `df[df$Name == "Jack", c("No1", "No2", "No3")]` or whatever your column names are

Comment: so using your first solution and selecting my columns using `across(df[3:11])` I get ` Error in UseMethod("mutate") : no applicable method for mutate applied to an object of class NULL `

Comment: @BrendaThompson I already showed the syntax `across(3:11` or `across(c(3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11)` or `across(all_of(names(df)[3:11])`

Comment: okay got it I thought i needed a closing bracket after `(3:11`.

Comment: @BrendaThompson the You can add the closing bracket but, it shouldn't close out the `across` i.e. `across(c(3:11), ....` is okay, but `across(3:11)` will close out the `across` without doing any operation